# Javascript function evaluation

Tags: javascript

I have function declared as :

```
function test(id, name) { 
  return id + "*-----*" + name
}
```

So when I do this `test(2,"Bob")` I get this :

```
"2*-----*Bob"
```

But when I declare array such as :

```
a = [2, "Bob"]
```

And inject these parameters into function like this :

```
test(a.join(','))
```

I get this :

```
"2,Bob*-----*undefined"
```

Which is not what I wanted. Why does it get interpreted like this? how can I make it output `"2*-----*Bob"` from the array that I have

Comment: An array join will give you a string, and NOT two parameters separated by comma, i.e. `"2,Bob"` is the array join result, but `"2", "Bob"` is what you wanted. You should make the second parameter optional and check whether the first parameter is an array. Then you can get the array content instead of the two string parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.apply(null,a)` will send the array `a` to the function and make the array elements the function arguments.  That is, a[0] will be the first function argument, a[1] will be the second argument, and so on but your function only has two arguments.

For more on this, read [The Mozilla Docs for Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 3):

`a.join(',')` will concat the array resulting in a string like `"2,Bob`". You have to pass both variables individually, like:

```
test(a[0], a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.join(',')` gives you one string, so you call your function `test` with one string (`"2,Bob"`) and the second parameter is `undefined`

If you want to allow an array as parameter, you can do it so:

```
function test(id, name) { 
    if (id.length > 1)
        return id[0] + "*-----*" + id[1]
    else
        return id + "*-----*" + name
}
```

Comment: I think because the question was edited, but I now also answer the edited part. Please remove the downvote or comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing only one argument to function which requires two arguments

Try

```
test(a.join(','), "foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test(a.join(','))
```

This passes exactly *one* parameter into the function, a string with a comma in it. `test(x)` will always only pass one parameter into the function, for any value of `x`.

You expect it to work as if you wrote `test(2,"Bob")`, but Javascript is not writing and recursively evaluating itself! You expect:

1. `a.join()` returns a string and writes it into the source code.
2. The resulting source code is read and executed.

The way it actually works:

1. The source code is read and executed.
2. `a.join()` returns one value which is used as the input to `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments packed up in an array to a function you need `apply()`

```
function test(id, name) { 
  return id + "*-----*" + name
}

var a = [2, "Bob"];

var result = test.apply(null, a); // See below

alert(result);
```

The first argument to `apply` will become 'this' inside the function, and the second argument is the actual array of values.